# Load test Using Visual Studio on Chrome as browser and Without using fiddler

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

i want to perform load test on visual studio without using fiddler and using chrome as browser as the application that i am using does not work in IE or Firefox 
can someone help me out with  procedure.

Comment: You need to be much more specific about your question. As it stands it is asking for a tutorial which is off-topic. Also, why without Fiddler?

Comment: because while using fiddler some of the steps are getting failed ,

Comment: On frist run of the test, the steps are getting passed, and when i am re-running the same test, some of the steps which used to pass earlier in first run gets failed

Comment: So your web test as recorded by Fiddler needs some debugging; it is probably dynamic data that has not been identified. That is just the same issue as if Visual Studio had recorded the test. Do some web searches for debugging web tests.

Comment: Fiddler by itself does not correlate your script. Try it with our StresStimulus add-on that will create all extractors and parameter automatically as described here http://www.stresstimulus.com/blog/post/visual-studio-load-testing-fixing-playback-errors-in-web-tests. After that save it as a webtest and open in Visual Studio.